# values passing from one window to other in cocoa application

Tags: cocoa

im new in cocoa ..
 can any one say how yo pass values fromm one window to other
i tried but ***windowController***
 not allowing to create instance of other class

Answer (score 0):

For passing one value to other Window ??

Window is just a view, you pass model's value, not view's values.

So, whenever you need to pass the value, you can use

1. Notification
2. Delegate
3. Shared Class.